# App autometic close after click on button

Tags: crash

I created login and register apk using firebase in MainActive ,it's run successful and data also store in firebase and attach empty  HomeActive ..and it successfully run and after login show home Active

But now after see android knowledge videos about navigation+bottom navigation.. I write the code in previous HomeActivity as it is same as youtube video and apk was run successful but didn't show HomeActivity it's back automatic afterlogin

Please solve this ,without any error it's run successful